# Having problems using the twitter streaming API

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm using the `'twitter'` npm package. I'm using the `'statuses/filter'` and `"track: 'keyword'"` filtering.

I can access whole objects endlessly, but when I try to manually filter any key, it will work for a short period and eventually hit an "undefined" error, or return undefined immediately. Specifically it hits an error and says the event.user object is undefined (the JSON object that I'm attempting to parse/filter).

edit: code in question:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var client = new Twitter({
  //environment variables to gain access safely
  consumer_key: process.env.tw_consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: process.env.tw_consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: process.env.tw_access_token,
  access_token_secret: process.env.tw_access_token_secret
})

client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'blah', track: 'yaddy', track: 'bleh'}, function(stream){

  console.log('listening'); 
  stream.on('data', function(event) {
    //this is where the error occurs, the event.user return undefined immediately or runs for a time then hits the same error, not JUST the property in question, but the whole object.
    console.log(event.user.url); 
  }); 
  stream.on('error', function(error){
    throw error;  
  })
});
```

Comment: Tough to know what's wrong without seeing any code from you, or any error messages. Please edit your question to include code+error. Otherwise, it's just guessing.

Comment: updated with code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that not every object returned is a user object, there are 'status' objects that are also sent. The trip up can be solved by allowing these objects through as well.